# Escape string before hashing?

Tags: php, hash

Simple question: Do I need to escape a string before hashing it, in other words, let's say a users password is "SF$@#$@#" do I need to escape that string before hashing it with PHP hash?

The answer is: no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not.

There are no characters that are "special" to a hash function - they treat the string as inert data.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.. sha1 and md5 will take any input